# Add a vector as legends in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a vector whose entries I want to be the titles of the graphs which of my plot. How do I do that? I know that I can only add 1 legend to a plot.

```
n=[2 4 6 8 10];
legend(int2str(n));
```

and it should appear as 5 different legends named "2", "4"....,"10".
I'm not really familiar how to change the vector n into a string vector.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy and intuitive may (in my opinion) would be to create the string corresponding to each element of the vector with `sprintf`. In my example I use a for-loop to generate curves, but the idea would the same if the curves were generated elsewhere. You can customize the text as you want of course. The code is based on as many curves as there are elements in `n`.

Example:

```
clear
clc

x = 1:10;

y = rand(1,10);
n=[2 4 6 8 10];

%// Initialize the cell containing the text. For each "n" there is a cell.
LegendString = cell(1,numel(n));

%// Plot every curve and create the corresponding legend text in the loop.
hold all
for k = 1:numel(n)

    plot(x,n(k)*y)
    LegendString{k} = sprintf('n = %i',n(k));
end

%// Display the legend
legend(LegendString)
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this is what you meant.

For a one-liner you can use `arrayfun` with `num2str` (thanks to @Divakar for the suggestion):

```
arrayfun(@(n) ['n = ',num2str(n)],n,'Uni',0)
```

Which gives a cell array that you can use directly in the call to `legend`.

Comment: One-liner `arrayfun(@(n) ['n = ',num2str(n)],n,'Uni',0)`?

Comment: haha I never think about `arrayfun` good idea! You can post it as an answer I'll +1

Comment: You're welcome! Be sure to try  @Divakar's suggestion as well its a nice and clean one-liner.

Comment: Nah, feeling too lazy! :)

Comment: Feel free to add that code into the answer though! Comments get deleted.

Comment: Oh I dit not know that I'll add it. Thanks!